# Pass run-time selected parameter to job without typing, GitLab CI (GUI)

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm working on an application deployment pipeline.

I have multiple environment that should be populated by application instances on demand.

[Desired behaviour: init_1 job triggers executor with specific parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Srwy.png)

- Run a parametrised job for deployment
- The above job gets parameter from user
- User can only select parameter values from a predefined list
- User should provide parameter to start the pipeline

What I tried:

- (1) I have the deploy job with manual trigger where I set the parameter as environment variable [eg: ENV_NAME].
  This solution works but error prone and it is pretty hard to rerun properly.
- (2) I have an init job that sets an environment variable [eg: ENV_NAME] with preset value [eg: dev]. The deploy job is triggered after the init.
  This solution works but it holds no real value.
- (3) I have multiple init jobs that can set a single environment variable eg: ENV_NAME] with specific values [eg: dev, stage1, stage2]. The deploy job should be triggered after environment variable is set by the init jobs.
  This solution does not work as init and deploy jobs are in two separate stages and the later does not start until all the jobs in the previous stage completes.
- (3.a) Same as above but here the init jobs are set to allow_failure.
  This solution does not work as init jobs are skipped totally, so deploy job does not get the required parameter.

```yaml
stages:
  - init
  - execute

init_1:
  stage: init
  rules:
    - when: manual
  script:
    - echo "INFRA_ID=pr1" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
  allow_failure: true

init_2:
  stage: init
  rules:
    - when: manual
  script:
    - echo "INFRA_ID=pr2" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
  allow_failure: true

executor:
  stage: execute
  script:
    - echo "Selected infrastructure $INFRA_ID"
```

- (3.b) Same as above but dependency is declared among init and deploy jobs.
  This solution does not work as deploy job depends on all of the init jobs.
- (4) I create N streams of init and deploy.
  This solution works but causes many duplicated code.

Do you see any solutions to my use-case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. It is not the best as it needs two consecutive manual approve, but it works.

### Concept

- Define initiator jobs in the init stage, setting the predefined values as environment variables (with artifacts.report.dotenv)
- Define a trigger step (trigger stage) that blocks the pipeline
- Define executor job in a later stage
- Set init and trigger jobs for manual
- Set the init jobs to allow_failure to make them optional (you only need one set of params at the time)

### Screenshots

[Pipeline in idle state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFDK8.png)

[Completed pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB3hJ.png)

### Code

```yaml
image: busybox:latest

stages:
  - init
  - trigger
  - execute

init_1:
  stage: init
  rules:
    - when: manual
      allow_failure: true
  script:
    - echo "INFRA_ID=pr1" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

init_2:
  stage: init
  rules:
    - when: manual
      allow_failure: true
  script:
    - echo "INFRA_ID=pr2" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

start:
  stage: trigger
  rules:
    - when: manual
  script:
    - echo "Pipeline is triggered with infra ID of $INFRA_ID"

executor:
  stage: execute
  script:
    - echo "Selected infrastructure $INFRA_ID"
```